# Query more objects with Parse/Swift

Tags: database, swift, parse-platform

How can I load an additional amount of objects into cells when the user has scrolled past the set limit. In this case I have the query limit set to 10 so when the user has seen all 10 and is scrolling I need it to load another 10.

Comment: Read about `PFQueryTableViewController`'s `loadNextPage` method here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html. This should be a good starting point.

Comment: See docs for PFQuery's skip: method.